# Getting electron-packager to use production build

Tags: reactjs, electron-packager

I have a `create-react-app` and I'm trying to figure out how to get `electron-packager` to create an .exe using the production build. It keeps using the development folder in `./src`

Running

`electron-packager . --no-prune --ignore=/node_modules --ignore=/e2e --overwrite --ignore=/src`

doesn't work. I also tried

`electron-packager ./build --no-prune --ignore=/node_modules --ignore=/e2e --overwrite --ignore=/src`

Here are the relevant entries in my `package.json`

```
{
    "homepage": "./",
    "main": "src/electron-entry.js",
    "build": {
        "target": "nsis",
        "dir": "./build"
    }
}
```

Here is my `loadURL` that points to the production build. In `electron-entry.js`. This works when I run in a dev environment.

```
new BrowserWindow(BrowserWindowProps).loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../build/index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
}));
```

Is the data in `electron-entry.js` even relevant to the directory `electron-packager` uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. I placed my electron entry file into the root directory and changed the `loadURL` to reflect that.

```
let startUrl = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL || url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/build/index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
});
mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);
```

Changed my package.json to reflect this change:

```
{
  "main": "./electron-entry.js",
}
```

Then I ran

`electron-packager . --no-prune --ignore=/node_modules --ignore=/e2e --overwrite --ignore=/src`